# Generate form - new lines and action

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm learning from Album tutorial for ZF 2.3.1.

In `add.phtml` I have the following code:

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('album', array('action' => 'add')));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formHidden($form->get('id'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('title'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('artist'));
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

The HTML output for this is:

```
<form action="&#x2F;album&#x2F;add" method="POST" name="album" id="album"><input type="hidden" name="id" value=""><label><span>Title</span><input type="text" name="title" value=""></label><label><span>Artist</span><input type="text" name="artist" value=""></label><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbutton" value="Add"></form>
```

However accoring to tutorial form should look like this: [image]

Questions:

1. Why ZF2 doesn't generate any new lines  tags as for example `<p>` or `<div>` between each line? In my browser all inputs are in the same line (maybe it's some styles issue not mentioned in tutorial) however I expected some extra tags will be generated
2. Why in action `/album/add` is changed into `&#x2F;album&#x2F;add` - are there any security reasons for that? Action for form is set `$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('album', array('action' => 'add')));` but when I use the same method to generate link url `<a href="<?php echo $this->url('album', array('action' => 'add')); ?>">test</a>` it creates `/album/add` url as I expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why ZF2 doesn't generate any new lines tags as for example `<p>` or `<div>` between each line?

One of the biggest criticisms of ZF1's forms system was that by programmatically generating form markup (using decorators) it made it difficult for users to customise the output. Consequently the helpers in ZF2 use minimal markup out of the box, allowing users to wrap the inputs with their own markup in views:

```
<?=$this->form()->openTag($form)?>

<?=$this->formHidden($form->get('id'))?>

<div class="form-row">
    <?=$this->formRow($form->get('title'))?>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <?=$this->formRow($form->get('artist'))?>
</div>

[etc.]
```

It is still possible to have this done automatically by extending the `formRow` helper.

> Why in action `/album/add` is changed into `&#x2F;album&#x2F;add`

I'd never noticed this before. I'd guess the form class is set to automatically escape HTML attribute values (a good thing in general). It still seems to work just fine so I wouldn't worry about this too much. Perhaps open an issue for it on Github if you think the behaviour should be changed.

Comment: The first thing makes sense however in tutorial there's no html code so I thought it's some configuration problem. Second thing I reported as issue at github as you recommended. Thank you for your answer